# Return (self) generated value from insert statement (no id, no returning)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, db2, ibm-midrange

sorry, if the question title is misleading or not accurate enough, but i didn't see how to ask it in one sentence.

Let's say we have a table where the PK is a String (numbers from '100,000' to '999,999', comma  is for readability only). 
Let's also say, the PK is not sequentially used.

Now i want to insert a new row into the table using java.sql and show the PK of the inserted row to the User. Since the PK is not generated by default (e.g. insert values without the PK didn't work, something like generated_keys is not available in the given environment) i've seen two different approaches:

in two different statements, first find a possible next key, then try to insert (and expect that another transaction used the same key in the time between the two statements) - is it valid to retry until success or could any sql trick with transaction-settings/locks help here? how can i realize that in java.sql?

for me, that's a disappointing solution, because of the non-deterministic behaviour (perhaps you could convince me of the contrary), so i searched for another one:

insert with a nested select statement that looks up the next possible PK. looking up other answers on generating the PK myself I came close to a working solution with that statement (left out the casts from string to int):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (pk,othercolumns)
VALUES(
(SELECT MIN(empty_numbers.empty_number) 
  FROM (SELECT t1.pk + 1 as empty_number 
    FROM mytable t1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2
    ON t1.pk + 1  = t2.pk

    WHERE t2.pk IS NULL
    AND t1.pk > 100000)
  as empty_numbers),
 othervalues);
```

that works like a charm and has (afaik) a more predictable and stable solution than my first approach, but: how can i possibly retrieve the generated PK from that statement? I've read that there is no way to return the inserted row (or any columns) directly and most of the google results i've found, point to returning generated keys - even though my key is generated, it's not generated by the DBMS directly, but by my statement.

Note, that the DBMS used in development is MSSQL 2008 and the productive system is currently a DB2 on AS/400 (don't know which version) so i have to stick close to SQL standards. i can't change the db-structure in any way (e.g. use generated keys, i'm not sure about stored procedures).

Comment: Look into [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) (which I believe is specific to SQL Server).

Comment: yep, but sql server specifics are not possible :-(

Comment: Why are you not developing with the same database system that you will use in production?  (BTW, technically, since IBM has not shipped a AS/400 since 2000, you are almost certainly on a newer iSeries, or Power System. The current version of the OS is called IBM i 7.1.)  Your DB2 system admin (or "security officer") should easily be able to create a test schema ("library") for you, if you can't do so yourself.  Why are your PK values string representations of numbers? Are you guaranteed to have only a single user process connected to your database that can insert rows into this table?

Comment: @WarrenT you are right with your points (and yes it's DB2 on iSeries), but unfortunately i have no influence on the production system, there are no real db admins or security officers in range and the only testdata provided by our direct customer are the mssql backups, i know of at least 5 applications using that table and imho the string-representation is some kind of historic mistake i can't possibly change (there are even stranger things going on in that project and especially that db, i just don't want to rage about that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 for i allows generated keys, stored procedures, user defined functions - pretty much all of the things SQL Server can do.  The exact implementation is different, but that's what manuals are for :-)  Ask your admin what version of IBM i they're running, then hit up the [Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html) for specifics.

The constraining factor is that you can't alter the database design; you are stuck with apparently multiple processes trying to INSERT while backfilling 'holes' in the existing keyspace.  That's a very tough nut to crack.  Because you can't change the DB design, there's nothing to be done except to allow for and handle PK collisions.  There's no SQL trick that'll help - the SQL way is to have the DB generate the PK, not the application.

There are several alternatives to suggest, in the event that *some change* is allowed.  All have issues needing a workaround, but that is unavoidable at this point due to the application design.

1. Create a UDF that all INSERT clients use to retrieve the next available PK.  Use a table of 'available numbers' and delete them as they are issued.
2. Pre-INSERT all the available numbers.  Force clients to do an UPDATE.  Make them FETCH...FOR UPDATE where (rest of data = not populated).  This will lock the row, avoiding collisions as well as make the PK immediately available.
3. Leave the DB and the other application programs using this table as-is, but have your INSERT process draw from a block of keys that's been set aside for your use.  Keep the next available number in an SQL SEQUENCE or an IBM i data area.  This only works if there's a very large hole in the keyspace that's not yet used.

Comment: hey, i'm a bit late with a comment, just want thank you for your answer and hints. i think you are right with the way you advise, so i will accept your answer. in my solution, i stepped back from the single query and changed the transaction_level (to serializable) and used two statements in that transaction (still afraid of locks, but tests worked well so far even with exception between both statements)